# wireless keyboard +installation

Tags: installation, wireless, keyboard, dual-boot, mouse

I have a running Win7 "system" with wireless keyboard and mouse. They are not running till windows is ready to start (login screen).

If I install Ubuntu (or any other system) I will not be able to use this keyboard and mouse.

Could have a wired keyboard, but is there any obstacle or hint to use this way?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for deletion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, they should work just fine as wireless keyboard and mice problems in Ubuntu are quite rare. Try a wubi ubuntu install and find out if they work, the only way to know is to test them.